# Subsetting data frame with multiple dollar signs in Shiny in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server

```
output$boxPlot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(input$fileSelect$input$cateSelect, main = "Box plot", ylab = "KJ")
  })
```

I am doing a interface that the user can select which file and which column of the data they want to plot. I was using a if condition to solve this issue but is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: What is the actual structure of `input$fileSelect`? As far as I know, there is no input that directly returns a data.frame. It would help immensely if you included a reproducible example.

Comment: This examples should help: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html , http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? (assuming that `input$fileSelect` is a data object and `input$cateSelect` is a character)

```
input$fileSelect[[input$cateSelect]]
```

Comment: Hi Nilsole, I have two inputs, one the named as fileSelect for a data frame file and the other one is named as cateSelect (column name stored in 'characters'). I tried your way but "subscript out of bounds" is the error message. Many thanks for your solution.

Comment: Well, the idea is to treat all inputs separately. `input$cateSelect` is different from `input$fileSelect`, that is why you cannot and should not concatenate them by dollar signs. Without having more information about your app, I cannot give you any more advice.